# Notepad++ document map only shows part of file

Tags: notepad++

I'm dealing with a large file of 4400 lines, but the document map only shows a portion of it, meaning I end up scrolling up and down which negates the usefulness of a doument map.

How can I make the document map show the entire length of the file?

Comment: To show the whole document map you have to reduce the font size in the main window (the document map font size is related to the main window font size). When you do this so the whole document map is visible the main window becomes unusable because the font is too small :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (as of version v6.8.5) it is not possible. In order to do that, you'd have to [download Notepad++ source code](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus) and develop it by yourself or wait for someone to do that.

Comment: 4 years ago the original question was asked. I was wondering if now, eind of September 2020 there has been a way to make it possible t show the full length.

Comment: @Sam No… Current version is 7.8.7 and it is still not possible. I didn't find a plugin to do that, either. I don't know if there's a forum where users can suggest features, but I guess that, if enough users ask for that feature, the developer team will make it.